# asp.net c#: Where clause gets bypassed with OR condition in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu, conditional-operator

**Database**: There are three tables in the database where IDs are int and Codes are `string` `datatype`. Exceptional with (countryId is string too).

- Country(countryId, countryCode...)
- Company(companyId, countryId, year, companyCode...)
- Center(centerId, companyId, year, centerCode...)

I am trying to get two specific **centers** which belong to two different **countries** where I know the **center's code**.

**User Action** : User selects an option (**Special**) from the **country** `DropDownList` which is an extra idem added to the `ListItem` where a random value (i.e. CORP) is given.

```
_DropDownListCountry.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Special", "CORP"));
```

**Expected** When user selects the above option from the _DropDownListCountry for a specific **year** then two items should be populated in another `DropDownList` (_DropDownListCenter). The item should be (e.g. 1111 and 2222) on the list. There is a relation with a **center** and **company** by **year**.

**Problem**: The result is shown as (1111, 2222, 2222) because there are two **centers** in the database but **year** is different. This happens when I used `||` in the `LINQ` query. But I don't understand (code wise) why is it happening. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Code**

```
public static IEnumerable<Center> RetriveCenterssByYear(short year)
    {
        List<Center> centers;
        using (var context = new crEntities())
        {
            centers = (from pc in context.Centers
                             join company in context.Companies on pc.CompanyID equals company.CompanyID
                             join co in context.Countries on company.CountryID equals co.CountryID
                             where pc.Year == year 
                                     && pc.CompanyID == company.CompanyID 
                                    && company.CountryID.Equals(co.CountryID)
                                    &&  pc.centerCode.Contains("1111")
                                    ||  pc.centerCode.Contains("2222")

                             select pc).ToList();

        }
        return centers;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some brackets around

```
pc.centerCode.Contains("1111")
||  pc.centerCode.Contains("2222")
```

so your condition shall look like

```
pc.Year == year 
&& pc.CompanyID == company.CompanyID 
&& company.CountryID.Equals(co.CountryID)
&&  (pc.centerCode.Contains("1111")
||  pc.centerCode.Contains("2222"))
```

as logical operators have equal priority, your query is currently interpreted as

```
(pc.Year == year 
&& pc.CompanyID == company.CompanyID 
&& company.CountryID.Equals(co.CountryID)
&&  pc.centerCode.Contains("1111"))
||  pc.centerCode.Contains("2222")
```

Comment: brackets after the where clause worked like a magic. 
where(pc.year == year...). Thanks a lot @Sergey Kudriavtsev.